# Formatting a list of floats to 2 Decimal Points

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, floating-point, decimal

I am trying to search though text to find Money EG £12.30 take the numbers and then sum them.I have managed to get to the point where I have a list of floats but I can't seem to get them to 2 decimal points. However like in the code below if I specify an element in the list like [0] for example then it formats that element to 2 decimal points.

So my question would be:
 How can I format the whole list to 2 decimal places bearing in mind I will have no idea how long the list will be.

```
import re

num_regex = re.compile(r'\d\d.\d\d')
file_name = input("Enter File Name to open: ")

text_file = open(file_name, 'r')
search_text = text_file.read()
search = num_regex.findall(search_text)
print("Numbers found:", search,)
new_search =[]
for item in search:
    new_search.append(float(item))
new_search[0] = "%.2f" % new_search[0]
print(new_search[0])
```

Comment: Use the [`decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) module instead of `float()`.

Comment: I have started reading it but it is much more complex I am very new to programming and it can be difficult to read such texts and actually take anything useful from them because of the jargon!

Comment: Money values are [fixed-point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_arithmetic), not floating-point. Using floating-point arithmetic on money is not wise because of the way computers represent floating-point values, which can lead to unexpected rounding.

Comment: SO confused what ever I will just make do with having it as 12.3 or what ever thanks a bunch :)

Comment: for item in resultList:
    (Decimal(item).quantize(Decimal('.02')))
    NewResultList.append(item)             is this right?

Comment: FWIW, here's a small demo of floating-point behaving unexpectedly: `a=[float(s) for s in '0.10 0.20 0.30'.split()];print(a[0]+a[1]-a[2] == 0.0)`. It prints `False`, even though `0.10+0.20-0.30==0.0` when you use exact arithmetic. Similarly, `print(0.1+0.2-0.3 == 0)` also prints `False`. Try `print(0.1+0.2-0.3)` to see why.

Answer (score 2):

> How can I format the whole list to 2 decimal places bearing in mind I will have no idea how long the list will be.

You use a `for` loop, iterating over your list of numbers, perhaps inside a list comprehension. Consider each of these:

```
formatted_list = []
for item in new_search:
    formatted_list.append("%.2f"%item)
print("Formatted List:", formatted_list)
```

Or, equivalently:

```
formatted_list = ["%.2f"%item for item in new_search]
print("Formatted List:", formatted_list)
```

Here is your entire program, using list comprehensions:

```
import re

num_regex = re.compile(r'\d\d.\d\d')
file_name = input("Enter File Name to open: ")

text_file = open(file_name, 'r')
search_text = text_file.read()
search = num_regex.findall(search_text)
print("Numbers found:", search,)
new_search =[float(item) for item in search]
print("Numbers found:", new_search,)
formatted_search =["%.2f"%item for item in new_search]
print("Numbers found:", formatted_search,)
```

Comment: Just sorted it out here is the final thing https://gist.github.com/anonymous/1ed68f0071bdb4143941#file-expend-py

Answer (score 1):

just format the variable before appending it to the list

```
item_price = []
price = float(input('What is the price of the item? '))
    fprice = '{:.2f}'.format(price)
    item_price.append(fprice)
```